Do neutrons have a higher entropy than protons?
Since free neutrons want to undergo beta decay into a proton while protons are relatively stable does that mean that neutrons have higher entropy than protons?

Having a higher entropy would lower the Gibbs free energy of the neutron (of course, ignoring the enthalpy difference). I'm confused on the reasoning in your question.

In a closed system, entropy always increases. This means that if neutrons had a higher entropy than protons, they would not decay into them.

(not to mention that entropy is a statistical phenomenon which is used to describe many-body systems. applying it to a single neutron may be possible in relativistic QCD, but i am not sure if it would yield useful results)

@paulina - Note that there is entropy in the electron and neutrino states too. If that is big enough then a high entropy neutron could decay into a lower entropy proton. However, I don't think this is a likely case.

It almost seems that this depends on the strength of the gravitational potential. In a neutron star, the neutron is stable, whereas electrons and protons cannot exist or are at least the unstable objects. Interesting question, thanks for that.
